# How do you use "which" as a relative pronoun?

Tags: pronouns

How do you use "which" as a <strike>preposition</strike> relative pronoun in chinese?

For example, I'm trying to translate：
 There is a cozy tea sitting area in our shop which is in front of the Campbell's farmers market on every Sunday

美週末星期天，在於商店裡，有一場舒適（座位／休息區）；我們的店位於農貿Campbell市場前。

My translation uses two complete sentences, but I want to make it a sentence followed by the <strike>preposition</strike> relative pronoun "which is in front of the Campbell's farmers market on every Sunday".

Answer (score 2):

I am a native Chinese and Linguistic major graduate student, I guess my answer is suitable:

**每周末我们位于Campbell农贸市场前面的商店里都会提供一个舒适的茶座。**

Or:
**每个周末,我们位于Campbell农贸市场前面的商店都会提供一个舒适的茶座。**

Either is Ok and I prefer the later one.

Comment: Good one, except that `Sunday` should be 周日 or 星期日。

Comment: Yeah you are right

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of word order and using 的:

位于我们商店前的 (A) 坎贝尔农场市场 (S) 每周日 (T) 有了 (V) 舒适的客厅 (O)

Comment: I might be misunderstanding what you wrote. It sounds like "Every Sunday, the farmers market located in front of our store has a cozy sitting area." The original sentence suggested that the seating area is inside the store.

Comment: Still the same principle: 在我们位于坎贝尔农场市场前的店里每周日有舒适的茶亭. Or you can split it up in a relative clause: 在我们店里，位于坎贝尔农场市场前，每周日有舒适的茶亭

Answer (score 1):

confirming answer #1:basic grammar， search web e。g。 for ＂relative
 clause in Chinese＂，

get e。g。 In Mandarin Chinese, the relative clause is similar to other adjectival phrases in that it precedes the noun that it modifies, and ends with the relative particle de. If the relative clause is missing a subject but contains an object (in other words, if the verb is transitive), the main-clause noun is the implied subject of the relative clause:[24

Comment: preposition?, usually called relative pronoun

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I updated the question to reflect this. also what do you mean by get e。g。? Can you give a example of a relative clause that is missing a subject? 

Here is an attempt. John， who writes poem, is imaginative. John,寫詩,很想像。 Here the relative pronoun, wrote a poem does not precede the subject, so the main clause noun John is the implied subject of the relative clause.

Comment: e.g.: exempli gratia 例如，比如；举例来说, English relative clauses usually (always?) have a subject, which can be the relative pronoun (as above), the relative pronoun can also represent the object, in which case the relative clause also contains a subject.

Answer (score 0):

每週末星期天 ，我們位於農貿Campbell市場前`的`店 裏有一場舒適（座位／休息區）。

Comment: “美” is typo, “每” is the correct one

Comment: Did you purposely omit 裏 in 店`裏`有以場. To me it is not clear that the sitting area is in the shop, since it reads as "the shop has a sitting area."

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. I've modified my answer